# Powershell set length of empty array

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, undefined, fill

I want to fill the array with gussed correct letters from the solution $Solution but everytime comes the error

"Index was outside the bounds of the array"

($arrayOutput).length=$LengthSolution doesnt work

```
$Solution="Apfelpfannekuchen"

$arraySolution = $Solution.ToCharArray()

$LengthSolution=($Solution|measure-object -Character).Characters

$arrayOutput@()a

while ($Input -notmatch $ Solution) {

[string]$Input = Read-Host "choose a letter"

    $arrayInput = $ Input.ToCharArray()

 

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $LengthSolution; $i++) {

        if($Input -eq $arraySolution[$i]){$arrayOutput[$i]=$Input}

        else {}

    }

    $arrayOutput

}
```

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71052722/edit) and fix the syntax errors (`$LengthSolution doesnt work` is not a valid expression, neither is `$arrayOutput@()a`)

Comment: You should also **NOT** use `$Input` as self-defined variable name because it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)

Comment: Can you check your code sample (try cutting and pasting from your question). When I run it I get… ```At /tmp/home/.code.tio.ps1:7 char:13
+ $arrayOutput@()a
+             ~~
Unexpected token '@(' in expression or statement.```